Extracting data from CSV - known cells
I have an Excel file which is created when the user inputs for a quote creation.
E.g. in cell "D3" you find the company name, in cell "D11" the expiry date of the quote.
Table looks like this:

I then save this Excel worksheet as CSV file.
As background, the system being quoted is built from row 29 onwards with various options added or optional items etc and that code worked before the first 28 rows were added with information.
Instead of my colleagues going into Latex/TexWorks, I've decided to make it easier by writing VBA Userform(s) collecting all the data which I had previously manually put into .tex file via \newcommand{\company}{Test company}.
Now I'm extracting \newcommand{\company} {\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{15}]{\excel}{}{\csvcoliv}} for company name. (Please comment if there is an easier way)
My problem is (several times):
\ifthenelse{\equal{\discount}{y}} (and other comparisons) are now giving errors where before they worked, so I am wondering if csv pulls in the data differently: Is \newcommand{\discount}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{18}]{\excel}{}{\csvcoliv}} different to \newcommand{\discount}{y}}? And why?
Update on 05/11/24:
.csv(when saving manual Excel file, I noticed that there are 4 different version: manual I use "CSV UTF-8" - I'm not sure if xlCSV is the same format. Regardless, the same errors occur.)
13,,Pricelist name,241105_0944_TCSystem.csv,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
14,,Creation Date,5/11/2024,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
15,,Company name,Test Company,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
16,,Company abbreviation,TC,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
17,,Quote number,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18,,Discount,y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
19,,Discount percentage,12.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
20,,Discount message,Repeat customer,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
21,,Recon system,n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
22,,Recon system text,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
23,,Expiry length,28,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
24,,Warranty length,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
25,,Optional items count,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
26,,Multiple systems?,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
27,,How many multiple?,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,,,{Total Price},,,,,,,,,,157458.7692,157,458,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,12,,{Discount},,,,,,,,,,18895.05231,18,895,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,,,{Discounted price},,,,,,,,,,138563.7169,138,563,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
7,12,,{Discount for 2 units},,,,,,,,,,18895.05231,18,895,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8,,,{Discounted price (per unit for 2 units)},,,,,,,,,,138563.7169,138,563,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,12,,{Discount for 3 units},,,,,,,,,,18895.05231,18,895,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,,,{Discounted price (per unit for 3 units)},,,,,,,,,,138563.7169,138,563,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11,,,{Combined price for 2 units},,,,,,,,,,277127.4338,277,127,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
12,,,{combined price for 3 units},,,,,,,,,,415691.1508,415,691,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,,,Extra Price,10000,,,,,,,,,10000,10,000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
System,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,{Test System},System,,147,458.77,6,,,,,,,,147458.7692,147,458,{\begin{minipage}[t]{15.7cm} \subsubsection*{XX} \begin{itemize} \item AA  \item BB \end{itemize} \end{minipage} \vspace{1cm} \begin{itemize}   \item CC \item DD \end{itemize} \hrulefill},\vspace{-1.5cm}\subsubsection*{\underline{Equipment Specifications}}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries \everypar{\hangindent0.5cm}}p{3.5cm} >{\everypar{\hangindent0.5cm}}X} aa – \nc  bb \\ cc – \nc dd\\ \end{tabularx} ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Add,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,2,,{First Add},,,,,,,,,,FALSE,0,0,{DescripTitle},{more description},2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,,,{Second Add},3022.836923,{all},,,,,,,,3022.836923,3,022,{DescripTitle},{more description},1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,,,{Third Add},4369.29,{all},,,,,,,,4369.292308,4,369,{DescripTitle},{more description},0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
Optional Extras,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,,{First opt},26973.69231,,,,,,,,,FALSE,26,973,{DescripTitle fopt},{more description},0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
,1,,{Second opt},3343.85,{all},,,,,,,,FALSE,3,343,{DescripTitle sopt},{more description},0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
Price option - but not listed,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,,,{Rural delivery},579.60,{all},,,,,,,,579.6,0,579,{DescripTitle},{more description},1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

.tex file:
    \documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

%%% select the required data %%%%
%Pricelist name
\newcommand{\pricelist}{241105_0944_VBA_Pricelist} 

%%% reading out data %%%%
%% select company name
\newcommand{\company} {\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{15}]{\excel}{}{\csvcoliv}} 

%Quote number/counter
\newcommand{\counter}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{17}]{\excel}{}{\csvcoliv}} 

%Discount applied?
\newcommand{\discount}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{18}]{\excel}{}{\csvcoliv}} %change to "y" if yes, "n" for no, "3u" for 3 units, "2u" for 2 units, "2ut" for 2 units plus total price

%Warranty length?
\newcommand{\wale}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{24}]{\excel}{}{\csvcoliv}} %change to "2" for 2 years, "1" if 1 year

%%%%%%% DON'T ALTER FROM HERE ONWARDS (except spacing and layout)%%%%
\newcommand{\system}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\excel}{2=\sys}{\sys}}
\newcommand\systemf{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\excel}{2=\sys}{\edef\MySystem{\sys}}}

\usepackage[textwidth=450pt, textheight=680pt,top=3cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry} %margins

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                   %% allow colour
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.4}

\usepackage{datetime} % dates - my altered dates below
\newdateformat{normal}{%
  \longdate \ordinaldate{\THEDAY} \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR} %normal date

\newcommand\twodigits[1] {\ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi}
\newdateformat{quoteNo}{%
   \THEYEAR--\twodigits{\THEMONTH}--\twodigits{\THEDAY}} % digit date for quote no.

\usepackage{csvsimple} % read Excel tables
\newcommand{\excel} {\pricelist.csv}
\newcommand{\comma}{, }
\newcommand{\commano}{,}
\newcommand{\nc}{&}
\newcommand{\ns}{\,}

\usepackage{enumitem} % dot points with indent
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \itemize[leftmargin=!,labelindent=5pt,itemindent=-10pt]
}{%
    \enditemize
}

\usepackage{longtable} % allows list to split over the page
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % for "continued on next page"

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\system \par %--> works now after revision of $
    
 \hfill \normal \today \\
\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{center}
\vspace{0.2cm}
    {\Large{Quote for \company} \par}
\vspace{0.1cm}
{\large Quote No: \quoteNo \today--\counter \par}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\end{center}

\vfill \csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\excel}{18=\specs}{\specs} %--> this gives me no output

\subsubsection*{Options Included In Price:}
\vspace{-0.2cm}
\csvreader[longtable= >{\everypar{\hangindent0.7cm}}p{15.6cm}, filter ifthen={\equal{\csvcolii}{2} \OR \equal{\csvcoli}{1}}, table head= \multicolumn{1}{r}{{{\hfill \scriptsize \textit{ Continued on next page}}}} \\ \endfoot \endlastfoot]{\excel}{17=\db, 18=\de}{ \begin{myitemize} \vspace{-0.9cm} \item\textbf{\db} \de \end{myitemize}}

\discount
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\discount}{y}} --> this gives me an error although \discount declared as y
%   {
    % discount
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{\huge{\color{light-gray} Price:  \qquad  \$\,\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{3}]{\excel}{15=\pricel,16=\pricer}          {\pricel,\pricer}   \quad plus GST}}\\
    \vspace{0.4cm} % adjust spacing here
    \end{center}
%   }
%{}%else
\color{black}
\subsubsection*{Quoted price also includes:}

\wale
 \begin{itemize}

%\ifthenelse{\equal{\wale}{2}} --> this gives me an error although \wale declared as 1
%{\item \textbf{24-month warranty} on all items, including options purchased \\
%}
%{}%else
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\wale}{1}} --> this gives me an error although \wale declared as 1
%{
\item 1 year warranty on all items, including options purchased \\
%}
%{}%else
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


Make sure that you export the CSV in a format that is understood by the parser. Although the C in CSV stands for comma, MS Office often exports CSV with semicolon as cell delimiter. Best would be if you could provide a compilable example of your code.

please provide a minimal example of both your .tex and your .csv input so we can reproduce the problem(s). (1) sounds like an expansion issue, but I've always used textmerg for .csv data. (this isn't a recommendation - just to say I'm not familiar with the package.) but this is just a guess based on insufficient data.

Why don't you write your VBA script in a way that already fetches the cell contents, instead of telling a LaTeX package in which row/column the data is inside the CSV?

@cfr: How do I upload the .csv file?

@Skillmon: The system is built choosing from 24 different systems (one choice possible) plus 100+ add-ons which can be included or listed as options (0-100+ possible). I'm not sure how else to combine. (The company provides the pricelists (per system) in Excel). Could you explain further how else I could approach the problem. Thanks

you don't upload the file. you make a minimal version with just enough data to demonstrate the problem and paste it into your question.

why don't you just remove the first 28 rows before reading into latex? (not by hand, obviously.)

@cfr: I will need those first 28 rows to have all the information of company name etc. which the user (my colleagues) just put in using VBA. (As explained, I can create a file without those 28 lines and then put the info into .tex myself; but my colleagues struggle, so trying to make it easier by creating UserForm (which also checks for errors or missing info).

I don't mean change the original: why can't you have a second copy which you pre-process to remove those rows and whatever else? the second copy is just an intermediate, temporary file like any other except it is produced prior to, rather than during, compilation. (I don't even know what VBA is, so maybe I just have a very different model in mind ....)

My point was, why don't you put the contents of the 28 first lines into TeX using VBA, so let VBA create what you created by hand.

@Skillmon Where am I able to read more about it? I struggle already to open TeX file after saving/manipulating my CSV file; tried Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXworks\TeXworks.exe""" & filenameT & """", vbNormalFocus, but gives me error '53' (even though filename exists since copied - just .exe file opens)

I'm not sure what exactly you attempt to do. You can just dump the cellcontents into a file containing things like \newcommand\mydatathingy{<cellcontents>}. Why do you want to open that file in TeXworks after that?

@Skillmon: I've written our quotes to be generated in TeXworks. We have 24 different systems plus over 100 options that can be added. I can manipulate the .tex file and enter customer's name etc, however, my colleagues struggle. Therefore I've just created a VBA Userform (ok, several to capture all options) asking for those details which I manually typed into .tex I see how \newcommand{\company} {Test Customer} can be created in Excel; however, how do I read it into the .tex file from the CSV created by Excel file?

By not exporting to csv but directly writing into a .tex file using VBA?

@Skillmon: Could you please provide me with a link to an example - I can only find .txt examples and Open filenameT For Output As #1 doesn't open an .tex file

This is a (La)TeX site, sorry. I'm no VBA programmer and never wanted to be one :) But TeX doesn't care for the file extension, use the .txt examples, just use \input{whatever.txt} in your document if you do that (no idea why you shouldn't be able to specify a file name with .tex at the end though).
